# Should or shouldn't I mask the results of XGETBV before using them for XSETBV?

Tags: x86, x86-64, avx, bare-metal

I am trying to execute some UEFI applications.

I found this code crashes on VirtualBox (`test success` is not printed while `test start` is printed):

```
#include <stdint.h>

void* ConOut;
uint64_t (*OutputString)(void* protocol, void* string);

void printChar(int c) {
    unsigned char data[4] = { (unsigned char)c };
    if (c == '\n') printChar('\r');
    OutputString(ConOut, data);
}

void printString(const char* str) {
    while (*str != '\0') printChar((unsigned char)*(str++));
}

void entry(void* unused, uint64_t* table) {
    (void)unused;

    ConOut = (void*)table[8];
    OutputString = (uint64_t (*)(void*, void*))((uint64_t*)ConOut)[1];

    printString("waiting for breakpoint set...\n");
    {
        volatile int j;
        for (j = 0; j < 1000000000; j++);
    }

    printString("test start\n");

    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        /* marker for setting breakpoint */
        "cmp $0xdeadbeef, %%eax\n\t"
        /* turn on OSXSAVE */
        "mov %%cr4, %%rax\n\t"
        "or $0x40000, %%rax\n\t"
        "mov %%rax, %%cr4\n\t"
        /* read XCR[0] */
        "xor %%eax, %%eax\n\t"
        "xor %%edx, %%edx\n\t"
        "xor %%ecx, %%ecx\n\t"
        "xgetbv\n\t"
        /* write XCR[0] */
        "xsetbv\n\t"
    : : : "%eax", "%ecx", "%edx");
    
    printString("test success\n");

    for (;;) __asm__ __volatile__ ("cli\n\thlt\n\t");
}
```

Compilation command:

```
C:\MyInstalledApps\TDM-GCC-64\bin\gcc -Wall -Wextra -nostdlib -e entry -m64 -Wl,--subsystem=10 minimum_test.c -o minimum_test.efi
```

From my examination, I found that `EDX:EAX` is set to `00000000:0000001f` via the `xgetbv` instruction and `xsetbv` causes `#GP` (interrupt vector 13) fault seeing the value.

Strangely, when I execute the `xgetbv` instruction via stepping on VirtualBox, it sets `EDX:EAX` to `00000000:00000001` and therefore no fault happens and `test success` is printed.

Refering [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-sdm.html), I found that it says this about XGETBV:

> If fewer
> than 64 bits are implemented in the XCR being read, the values returned to EDX:EAX in unimplemented bit loca-
> tions are undefined.

Then, about XSETBV:

> Protected Mode Exceptions
> #GP(0)
> If the current privilege level is not 0.
> If an invalid XCR is specified in ECX.
> If the value in EDX:EAX sets bits that are reserved in the XCR specified by ECX.
> If an attempt is made to clear bit 0 of XCR0.
> If an attempt is made to set XCR0[2:1] to 10b.

This case is setting reserved bits according to the `EDX:EAX` value. As the values of unimplemented bits returned from XGETBV are undefined, it looks like reasonable to mask the results of XGETBV before passing them to XSETBV.
The value to use for masking can be obtained by [CPUID with EAX=0x0D, ECX=0](https://sandpile.org/x86/cpuid.htm#level_0000_000Dh).
After adding some code to apply masking, XSETBV worked well on VirtualBox.

On the other hand, the Intel manual also say this about XSETBV:

> Undefined or reserved bits in an XCR should be set to values
> previously read.

This looks like the reserved bits should be set to values obtained via XGETBV and I shouldn't apply maskimg to force the bits to become zero.

As a conclusion, should or shouldn't I mask the result of XGETBV by the valid bits obtained via CPUID before passing them to XSETBV?

---

What I found as related but not duplicate question:

- [assembly - vmovdqa not working in virtualbox? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48614808/4062354)

  - This question is claiming that `xsetbv` after `xgetbv` works, but I found it didn't work on VirtualBox.
- [assembly - XSetgv crashes in my bare metal software - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34446218/4062354)

  - This question is directly setting EAX and EDX instead of using XGETBV.
- [c - Using XSETBV to write to XCR0 creates a general protection fault in a VM on hardware that supports MPX - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61788368)

  - This question is on VMWare, but my question is on VirtualBox.
  - This question says "if I don't manipulate `xcr0` and just read its value and write it back, things seem to work fine", but in my experiment just writing value read caused `#GP` fault.

---

Host environment:

- Windows 10 Home (x64)
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz 2.59GHz
- RAM 16.0 GB
- VirtualBox 6.1.18 r142142 (Qt5.6.2)

Guest (VM) environment:

- Operating System: Other/Unknown (64-bit)
- Base Memory: 128 MB
- Chipset: PIIX3
- Enable I/O APIC
- EFI: Enabled
- 1 CPU
- Acceleration: VT-x/AMD-V, Nested Paging, PAE/NX
- Paravirtualization Interface: Default

---

Full code for testing:

```
#include <stdint.h>

void* ConOut;
uint64_t (*OutputString)(void* protocol, void* string);

void printChar(int c) {
    unsigned char data[4] = { (unsigned char)c };
    if (c == '\n') printChar('\r');
    OutputString(ConOut, data);
}

void printString(const char* str) {
    while (*str != '\0') printChar((unsigned char)*(str++));
}

void printInt(uint64_t value, int radix, int minDigits) {
    char vStr[128] = "";
    char* pStr = vStr + 120;
    int digits = 0;
    do {
        *(pStr--) = "0123456789ABCDEF"[value % radix];
        value /= radix;
        digits++;
    } while (value > 0 || digits < minDigits);
    printString(pStr + 1);
}

void stop(void) {
    __asm__ __volatile__(
        "cli\n\t"
        "1:\n\t"
        "hlt\n\t"
        "jmp 1b\n\t"
    );
}

void entry(void* unused, uint64_t* table) {
    uint32_t eax, ebx, ecx, edx, cs, cr0, xcr0_low, xcr0_high;
    uint32_t cpuid_max, eax_mask, edx_mask;
    unsigned char src_test[32], dst_test[32] = {0};
    int i;
    (void)unused;

    ConOut = (void*)table[8];
    OutputString = (uint64_t (*)(void*, void*))((uint64_t*)ConOut)[1];

    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "xor %%eax, %%eax\n\t"
        "cpuid\n\t"
    : "=a"(eax), "=b"(ebx), "=c"(ecx), "=d"(edx));
    printString("CPUID.00H: EAX=0x"); printInt(eax, 16, 8);
    printString(", EBX=0x"); printInt(ebx, 16, 8);
    printString(", ECX=0x"); printInt(ecx, 16, 8);
    printString(", EDX=0x"); printInt(edx, 16, 8);
    printChar('\n');
    if (eax < 1) {
        printString("CPUID.01H not supported!\n");
        stop();
    }
    cpuid_max = eax;

    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "mov $1, %%eax\n\t"
        "cpuid\n\t"
    : "=a"(eax), "=b"(ebx), "=c"(ecx), "=d"(edx));
    printString("CPUID.01H: EAX=0x"); printInt(eax, 16, 8);
    printString(", EBX=0x"); printInt(ebx, 16, 8);
    printString(", ECX=0x"); printInt(ecx, 16, 8);
    printString(", EDX=0x"); printInt(edx, 16, 8);
    printChar('\n');
    if (!((ecx >> 26) & 1)) {
        printString("xsave (ECX[26]) not supported!\n");
        stop();
    }

    if (cpuid_max >= 0x0D) {
        __asm__ __volatile__ (
            "mov $0xd, %%eax\n\t"
            "xor %%ecx, %%ecx\n\t"
            "cpuid\n\t"
        : "=a"(eax), "=b"(ebx), "=c"(ecx), "=d"(edx));
        printString("CPUID.0DH: EAX=0x"); printInt(eax, 16, 8);
        printString(", EBX=0x"); printInt(ebx, 16, 8);
        printString(", ECX=0x"); printInt(ecx, 16, 8);
        printString(", EDX=0x"); printInt(edx, 16, 8);
        printChar('\n');
        eax_mask = eax;
        edx_mask = edx;
    } else {
        printString("CPUID.0DH not supported\n");
        eax_mask = UINT32_C(0xffffffff);
        edx_mask = UINT32_C(0xffffffff);
    }

    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "mov %%cs, %%ax\n\t"
        "movzwl %%ax, %0\n\t"
        "mov %%cr0, %%rax\n\t"
    : "=g"(cs), "=a"(cr0));
    printString("CPL check: CS=0x"); printInt(cs, 16, 4);
    printString(", CR0=0x"); printInt(cr0, 16, 8);
    printChar('\n');
    if (!cr0 & 1) {
        printString("not in protected mode!\n");
        stop();
    }
    if ((cs & 3) != 0) {
        printString("CPL is not zero!\n");
        stop();
    }

    printString("waiting for breakpoint set...\n");
    {
        volatile int j;
        for (j = 0; j < 1000000000; j++);
    }

    printString("turning on OSXSAVE\n");
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        /* turn on OSXSAVE */
        "mov %%cr4, %%rax\n\t"
        "or $0x40000, %%rax\n\t"
        "mov %%rax, %%cr4\n\t"
    : : : "%eax");

    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        /* marker for setting breakpoint */
        "cmp $0xdeadbeef, %%eax\n\t"
        /* read XCR[0] */
        "xor %%eax, %%eax\n\t"
        "xor %%edx, %%edx\n\t"
        "xor %%ecx, %%ecx\n\t"
        "xgetbv\n\t"
    : "=a"(xcr0_low), "=d"(xcr0_high) : : "%ecx", "cc");
    printString("XCR[0] = ");
    printInt(xcr0_high, 16, 8); printChar(':');
    printInt(xcr0_low, 16, 8); printChar('\n');

    xcr0_low |= 6;

#if 0
    printString("applying mask\n");
    xcr0_low &= eax_mask;
    xcr0_high &= edx_mask;
#else
    (void)eax_mask; (void)edx_mask;
#endif

    printString("new XCR[0] will be: ");
    printInt(xcr0_high, 16, 8); printChar(':');
    printInt(xcr0_low, 16, 8); printChar('\n');

    printString("turning on AVX\n");
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        /* marker for setting breakpoint */
        "cmp $0xdeadbeef, %%ecx\n\t"
        /* turn on AVX */
        "xor %%ecx, %%ecx\n\t"
        "xsetbv\n\t"
    : : "a"(xcr0_low), "d"(xcr0_high) : "%ecx", "cc");

    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) src_test[i] = 123 * (i + 1);
    printString("testing AVX instruction\n");
    printString("src:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        printInt(src_test[i], 16, 2);
        printChar((i + 1) % 16 == 0 ? '\n' : ' ');
    }
    printString("dest before:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        printInt(dst_test[i], 16, 2);
        printChar((i + 1) % 16 == 0 ? '\n' : ' ');
    }
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "vmovups (%0), %%ymm0\n\t"
        "vmovups %%ymm0, (%1)\n\t"
    : : "r"(src_test), "r"(dst_test));
    printString("dest after:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        printInt(dst_test[i], 16, 2);
        printChar((i + 1) % 16 == 0 ? '\n' : ' ');
    }

    printString("test done.\n");
    stop();
}
```

Output from VirtualBox:

```
CPUID.00H: EAX=0x00000016, EBX=0x756E6547, ECX=0x6C65746E, EDX=0x49656E69
CPUID.01H: EAX=0x000906ED, EBX=0x00010800, ECX=0x56DA220B, EDX=0x178BFBFF
CPUID.0DH: EAX=0x00000007, EBX=0x00000340, EDX=0x00000340, EDX=0x00000000
CPL check: CS=0x0038, CR0=0xC0010033
waiting for breakpoint set...
turning on OSXSAVE
XCR[0] = 00000000:0000001F
new XCR[0] will be: 00000000:0000001F
turning on AVX
```

Output when I execute the program directly on my PC:

```
CPUID.00H: EAX=0x00000016, EBX=0x756E6547, ECX=0x6C65746E, EDX=0x49656E69
CPUID.01H: EAX=0x000906ED, EBX=0x00100800, ECX=0x77FAFBBF, EDX=0xBFEBFBFF
CPUID.0DH: EAX=0x0000001F, EBX=0x00000240, ECX=0x00000440, EDX=0x00000000
CPL check: CS=0x0038, CR0=0x80000013
waiting for breakpoint set...
turning on OSXSAVE
XCR[0] = 00000000:00000001
new XCR[0] will be: 00000000:00000007
turning on AVX
testing AVX instruction
src:
7B F6 71 EC 67 E2 5D D8 53 CE 49 C4 3F BA 35 B0
2B A6 21 9C 17 92 0D 88 03 7E F9 74 EF 6A E5 60
dest before:
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
dest after:
7B F6 71 EC 67 E2 5D D8 53 CE 49 C4 3F BA 35 B0
2B A6 21 9C 17 92 0D 88 03 7E F9 74 EF 6A E5 60
test done.
```

Comment: Is your VirtualBox set up to pass through AVX support?  If not, it might be silently masking away your attempts to XSETBV the AVX-enable bits.  I didn't try to manually decode your CPUID results, but I see EAX=1/CPUID has different results for ECX.  (Some VMs default to being this way so it's possible to resume a VM image on a host without AVX support.  i.e. they limit the guest to some baseline set of CPUID feature flags.  For some, like `popcnt`, not advertizing support in CPUID isn't going to stop the machine insn from executing, but for AVX it is.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for comment. The top digit of CPUID.01H ECX from the VM is 5, so it is saying that AVX is supported (bit 28).

Comment: I think the `xgetbv / xsetbv` is always safe on a *physical machine*.  But `xgetbv` is not a sensitive instruction (it doesn't cause a VM-exit, so VBox doesn't know when it is executed) and thus is reads the XCR0 value of your host machine. However, VBox seems to disable MPX on the gues (making bits 3 and 4 of XCR0 not settable, as reflected in `CPUID.edx=0Dh,ecx=0.eax`). In short, this may be a quirk of VBox. I don't even think `xsetbv` actually faults, rather it causes a VM-exit and then VBox injects a fault (because I didn't find a way to disable MPX for a guest, so this may be emulated)